# How is `UIScreen.main.bounds.height - frame(in: .global).minY` below the screen edge in iOs?

Tags: ios, swift, swiftui

I was doing [this](https://www.vadimbulavin.com/swiftui-popup-sheet-popover/) tutorial, and I understand everything in it except this one extension.

```swift
private extension GeometryProxy {
    var belowScreenEdge: CGFloat {
        UIScreen.main.bounds.height - frame(in: .global).minY
    }
}
```

I made a test to see what is going on

```swift
import SwiftUI

struct ContentView: View {
    var body: some View {
        GeometryReader {gproxy in
            Button("Do something") {
                print("The bounds height is: \(UIScreen.main.bounds.height)")
                print("The frame global: \(gproxy.frame(in: .global))")
                print("The minY is: \(gproxy.frame(in: .global).minY)")
                print("The belowScreenEdge is: \(UIScreen.main.bounds.height - gproxy.frame(in: .global).minY)")
            }
        }
    }
}
```

and the printout I get in console is

```
The bounds height is: 844.0
The frame global: (0.0, 47.0, 390.0, 763.0)
The minY is: 47.0
The belowScreenEdge is: 797.0
```

My question is, how can 797.0 represent something below the screen?

Answer (score 0):

I see that belowScreenEdge is actually **screenHeight - gproxy.frame.y**

So it is basically calculating how much far away is the top of gproxy from the bottom of the screen.

If you see minY is: 47.0 and belowScreenEdge is: 797.0, total of which comes out to be screenHeight i.e. 844.0

I think you have misunderstood the part of 797.0 representing something below the screen?

Let me know if it helps or you have any more queries.

Thanks.